# Can't login to a remote server after uploading ssh key to the remote server

Tags: ssh, openssh, remote-login

I tried installing ssh-key on a remote server.
However I can't login into the remote server without using password

My effort is described in this...

[image: ssh_related]

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Your 'image' is only of text - please copy & paste the text into your question, it is far easier to read, copy from & use in answers (we can't copy & paste from your pictures of text).  We can help you format your question where text is involved, if you can't figure it out.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1102133/sign-and-send-pubkey-signing-failed-agent-refused-operation This question may help, although I can't vouch for its effectiveness as I couldn't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search for my mistake, I found that `agent refused operation` problem can be rectified just by running one command in the terminal `ssh-add`. Looks like an ssh-agent is running already but it can not find any keys attached. To solve this add the private key identities to the authentication agent like `ssh-add`